# WMI - Getting DNS Config via Powershell

Tags: powershell

when attempting to run my script then I got the following output. So Computer Name is duplicating.
I am getting `{192.168.1.11, 192.168.1.12, $null}` in DNS.

Script :

```
  $Result=Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled = 'True'" -Property DNSServerSearchOrder,DNSHostname
  $output = new-object PSObject 
  $output | add-member NoteProperty "ComputerName" $Result.DNSHostname
  $output | add-member NoteProperty "DNSServerSearchOrder" $Result.DNSServerSearchOrder
  $output
```

Output :

```
ComputerName                   DNSServerSearchOrder                   
------------                   --------------------                   
{srv01, srv01}                 {192.168.1.11, 192.168.1.12, $null}
```

Comment: So $result has two objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Select-Object` when piping multiple results, like:

```
$Result | Select-Object -Property DNSHostname,DNSServerSearchOrder

DNSHostName DNSServerSearchOrder         
----------- --------------------
srv01       {192.168.1.11, 192.168.1.12}
srv01       {$null}
```

The reason there are two results is you have two enabled adapters. The second has no DNS servers set